# What is the difference between the Hindi keyboard layouts Bolnagri and Kagapa?

Tags: keyboard-layout, language-support

I am confused. What's the difference between these two Hindi keyboard layouts?

Answer (score 7):

I don't really know much about the Hindi language or either of those layouts, but you can have a look at both layout charts and compare them yourself to find out which one represents your physical keyboard best:

[image]

You can view these on your own machine using the commands

```
gkbd-keyboard-display -l $'in\tbolnagri'
gkbd-keyboard-display -l $'in\thin-kagapa'
```

or by setting one as your active input source and clicking the "Keyboard Layout Chart" button from the keyboard indicator (at least in Unity).

Comment: Looking at both keyboard layouts, it seems KaGaPa layout support more letters then Bolnagri. KaGaPa layout might be an updated version of Bolnagri. However, I may be wrong.